# Jmeter how to simulate a failure based on results of a condition fro Post Processor

Tags: jmeter

I have a situation where I check the response data and if there is a specific variable exist then I like to simulate a test failure even though that HTTP req code was 200. For example in Bean Post Processor I have:

```
if ( (prev.getResponseDataAsString().indexOf(Z2) >= 0) || (matches > 1) ){
    System.out.println(ctx.getCurrentSampler().getName() +" --> Failed ....")
}
```

I know how to do it when I want to set the result to success (prev.setResponseOK();) how do I do it if I want to set it to fail?  so the GUI shows red and not green?
Thank you

Comment: Hi, usually in stackoverflow when an answer helps, it gets accepted and/or upvoted by the user who posted the question

Answer (score 0):

See in [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

> Unlike the BeanShell Sampler, the JSR223 Sampler does not set the ResponseCode, ResponseMessage and sample status via script variables. Currently the only way to changes these is via the SampleResult methods:
>
> SampleResult.setSuccessful(true/false)

`prev` is a SampleResult object so you can mark it as failed:

```
prev.setSuccessful(false)
```

> prev - (SampleResult) - gives access to the previous SampleResult

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a use case for a [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) which you can use in order to conditionally set pass/fail criteria for a Sample basing on presence/absence of certain patterns in the response data.

Here is an example of failed HTTP Request sampler with 200 status code due to absence of the anticipated data in the response:

[image: JMeter Response Assertion]

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) for more details.

---

With regards to [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) which you're violating by the way by using Beanshell PostProcessor:

- You should be using built-in JMeter test elements where possible
- If you have to go for scripting make sure to choose the most performing option which is [unfortunately not Beanshell](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

Comment: in Response Assertion how do I check for this?  if ( (prev.getResponseDataAsString().indexOf(Z2) >= 0) || (matches > 1) )  in Response Assertion you can only check for specific strings, not a condition which is my case, I want to see if I have multiple occurrences of a specific string and also I want to make sure that I dont have this other string

Comment: You can use a Perl-5 style regular expression in case of "Contains" and/or "Matches"